# hibernate Query by primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I wanna create query by primary key.
Supposed I have class primary key, PersonKey, the properties is name and id.

I have Person class, the property is PersonKey, address, DOB.

Now, I wanna search person by primary key.

First, I create instance of PersonKey, and set the name become: joe, and id become:007

can I get the person by ID, by pass the key variable ???

person.findByKey(someKey); , but the logic do not criteria

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can. Assuming the `PersonKey` is `Serializable`, simply pass it to the `get` method:

```
PersonKey pk = new PersonKey(007l, "joe");
Person person = (Person) session.get(Person.class, pk);
```

Comment: Why PersonKey needs to be serializable?

Comment: @Reddy Because of the signature of `Session.get(Class, Serializable)`

Comment: Thanks Pascal, but why hibernate forcing serialization?
As per my understanding hibernate will generate SQL statements and then only sends over network to Database, in this case serialization is unnecessary.. right?

Comment: Any idea why this gives me java.lang.IllegalStateException: No criteria query roots were specified
 at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.CriteriaQueryImpl.validate(CriteriaQueryImpl.java:253)