# Hibernate - How to retrieve data from table with two primary keys

Tags: hibernate

my table name is store_record . it has "code" and "status" are two primary keys . in hibernate i created persistence class for that table. it created two classes , first class has code and status setter and getter method and an other class  first class object and remaining table fields get setter and getter methods.  Now my problem is i want get data from that table using only one primary key (like code) how can i write query in hibernate for this problem.

my table is like this

```
           desc branches;
+----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| cod_ifsc_bank_branch | varchar(24) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| txt_bank_branch_name | varchar(24) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| cod_rec_status       | char(1)     | NO   | PRI | A       |       |
| txt_last_maker_id    | varchar(16) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| dat_last_maker       | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
|       |
+----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

in this table has two primary keys  one is 'cod_ifsc_bank_branch' and an other one is 'cod_rec_status ' . but i want to get data using one primary key is like 'cod_ifsc_bank_branch' now how can i write query in hibernate for this problem

thank in advance 
DNMurthy

Comment: I assume the first class is the parent class of the second class  but please add your code classes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847728/hibernate-query-by-primary-key

Comment: @eduardohl: it's not a duplicate, the OP wants to query by only a part of the kay (cit.: "using only one primary key (like code)").

Comment: It is NOT 2 primary key, it is in fact a composite key.  And, both value when combined together give you the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

It is NOT 2 primary key, it is in fact a composite key. And, both value when combined together give you the primary key.

You should have only 1 class mapped for entity, and another class for the composite ID (you may omit it if you use a Hibernate-specific feature).

An attribute which is part of the primary key has no difference from other normal attributes, and you can use it as query criteria just as other normal attribute.  For example:

(not very accurate mapping, just give you an idea)

```
@Entity
class Foo {
  @EmbededId
  private FooId id;

  @Column(updatable=false, insertable=false)
  private String code;    // part of the ID, but you may also map it again with 
                          // updatable, insertable = false

  @Column(updatable=false, insertable=false)
  private FooStatus status;  // Ditto
}

@Embeddable
class FooId {
  @Column
  String code;

  @Column
  FooStatus status;
}
```

then it is fine for you to have a query like this:

```
from Foo where foo.code = 'SOME_CODE'
```

or even (haven't tested, I think it may work)

```
from Foo where foo.id.code = 'SOME_CODE'
```